# Applescript run script every 5 seconds

Tags: applescript

I am trying to run the following code as a coroutine. Is there any way to accomplish this?

`repeat
delay 5
log theScript
end repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `on idle` handler and save the script as application

```
on idle
    log theScript
    return 5
end idle
```

In case of an AppleScriptObjC application you can't use the `idle` handler, an alternative is `NSTimer` of the Foundation framework.

```
property timer : missing value

on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification
    set timer to current application's NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0  target:me selector:"timerFired:" userInfo:(missing value)  repeats:true
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on timerFired:aTimer
    log "timerFired"
end timerFired
```

Comment: I tried putting this directly in my app, but it is not working. `on idle
    display notification "worked"
    return 5
end idle`

Comment: It'a supposed to work in any script saved as application.

Comment: I just put it into my app delegate script in xcode and ran it.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you're talking about an AppleScriptObjC class, not about a ***script***. In this case the `idle` handler does not work. You need to use Foundation `NSTimer`.

Comment: can other actions run while this is running?

Comment: Yes, `NSTimer` works asynchronously. The behavior is very similar to the `idle` handler.